# Creating 'Page Number' like in a book, in database

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I am working on a project where I have to create a 'canvas' where user can save 'notes'[image]. There are multiple sections in the canvas and the user must be logged in to save anything into the canvas. Also, there are canvas numbers, like book numbers which show the different pages of canvases. I am into the data modelling stage for the project right now.

My idea right now is to create a base-table 'User' and user one-to-many relationship with each section in canvas. The base class also has a field called 'canvas-number'.

My question is, how can I create a data model, where I can say, now that this canvas is going to be saved by the user, lets start the canvas with the next number. Am I being clear?  So whenever the user clicks on the canvas number, he is shown only the notes from that canvas-number. If my question is unclear, please ask whats unclear,rather then just marking it not productive and all. Thank you.

P.S : I am using PostgreSQL

Below is the basic schema.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? Also, are you looking for something ***similar to*** [this?](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

Comment: Yes..I have already implemented the basic schema in PowerArchitect, was just looking how to export as an image. No, I don't need the TOP clause, I want to return the notes saved by per user/per canvas number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand

- A canvas belongs to exactly one user
- A user can have many canvases
- A canvas can have many notes

So with a natual key concept and canvas number 1, 2, 3 per user:

- user (**loginname**, firstname, lastname etc.)
- canvas (**loginname**, **canvasno**, creationdate, whatever ...)
- note (**loginname**, **canvasno**, **noteno**, position, text, ...)

To get the next canvas number you would select max(canvasno) for the loginname.

With a natual key concept and unique canvas number (so one user may have canvas 1, 5 and 7 and another 2, 3, 13 etc.):

- user (**loginname**, firstname, lastname etc.)
- canvas (**canvasno**, creationdate, whatever ...)
- note (**canvasno**, **noteno**, position, text, ...)

You would get the next canvas number by selecting max(canvasno) or simply use an auto-increment column.

With an ID concept:

- user (**id_user**, loginname, firstname, lastname etc.)
- canvas (**id_canvas**, id_user, canvasno, creationdate, whatever ...)
- note (**id_note**, id_canvas, noteno, position, text, ...)

To get the next canvas number, you would select the max(canvasno) for the user's ID.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten Kettner : But the canvas has multiple sections inside, which are saved in seperate tables. Right now I have one base user table and tables for all sections with foreign key relation to base user and also a canvas number variable in all tables. So for retreival I can use userid, canvasnumber and get notes for specific user and that specific canvas.. Seems ok now, any optimizations you can think of?

Comment: I don't know about your sections. Do all canvases have the same sections, like upper-left corner, lower-left, upper-right, lower-right? Or does every canvas have its own sections?

Comment: Every canvas has its own section. same sections in all canvas. Like todays-task, tomorrows-task, and in those section there are notes.

Comment: So you need a section table containing all sections, and each note gets an additional column for the section it belongs to.

Comment: Exactly. I will edit the image, thats how my schema looks like now. All the tables attached to base user are sections of a canvas. Right now my id for data retreival, adding, deleting is to pass userid, canvasnumber and do it. Seems like the only option to me right now.

Comment: Hm, I must admit I'm not good at reading such diagrams. Why does every table habe a canvas number? Why does a person have a canvas number? It should be vice versa: a canvas belongs to one person.

Comment: And just for clarification: Bold columns in the tables in my answer mean primary key. So either I use natural composite keys thus having the canvas number in many keys or I use a key concept and the canvas number only exists as a non-key column in the canvas table.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. But the user has the ability to create a new canvas. Sorry, that person name is because I modified an old project, ignore it. Just one last question, when the user saves this canvas and goes to new canvas with lets say id=2, how would I retrieve notes only from canvas=1;

Comment: Notes belong to a canvas. So with a composite key concept: `select * from notes where loginname='USERA' and canvasno=1;`. With an ID concept: `select * from notes where id_canvas in (select id from canvas where canvasno=1 and id_user in (select id from user where loginname='USERA'));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63348/discussion-between-orici-and-thorsten-kettner).

Comment: Hi, I have posted my question in chat. Can you please check it? Typing it here again :Hello, Thanks for the comment. I am sorry I moved this to chat, it was getting too long there. I think I am missing some basic concepts. If there is a one-to-many relationship between the baseuser class and the sections, then what you said means that database works like a snapshot. So as soon as the canvasnumber is changed, all the sections with its notes and canvas number are stored and I don't need to worry about them. is that correct?